# How to get value by id in twitter typeahead?

Tags: typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I implemented twitter typeahead to enable a user to choose his location. He types his location `name` then select from the list and the `id` of the location that he selected will be posted on the form.

This works fine, and assume i have this following list:

```
[
    United States : 1,
    Canada : 2,
    England: 3,
    China: 4,
    India: 5,
    .... // other locations
]
```

Now a user select canada and submit the form, the id `2` is saved in the database. But if the user goes back to the same form, i make a query to get the location that he choose, in this case the id `2` will be returned.

How do i auto select Canada in the typeahead to display the location he selected?

i tried

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead('val', value) //where value = 2
```

but this does not work

Comment: i don't get any errors, but this just put the `2` in the typeahead instead of `canada`

Comment: Please create [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: here is a js fiddle i just created. the fiddle is when you select a location, the id is obtained and this id is stored in database when the form is submitted. now when i need to take the saved data from db and display in the typeahead. fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mu3cxv9w/

Comment: I'm not familiar with typeahead, but can't you do just an AJAX request to fetch the name from the JSON data, and add it to the inputs? [Look at the example](https://jsfiddle.net/mu3cxv9w/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Because the typeahead control is "just" an html input, there is no built in mechanism for populating a text value based on an id value.  You have to do that part yourself.

[I've created a fiddle to demonstrate.](https://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/0qzabbnt/2/)

You can use a variety of different methods to accomplish this, but I use `on focus` to handle it in my implementation.

```
.on('focus', function() {
    if (defaultOption.length) {
      var nm = $.map(locs, function(obj) {
        if (obj.id === defaultOption)
          return obj.name; // or return obj.name, whatever.
      });
      console.log(nm);
      $(this).data().ttTypeahead.input.trigger('queryChanged', nm);
    }
  });
```

In this case, I am providing a defaultValue (which would be what comes back from the database) and then adding it to the source as the first item and then triggering the query changed event.

Another way to handle it would be to simple pre-populate the expected value in the input box. I've included a demonstration of one way you could handle this at the end of the linked fiddle.  The code checks for a default value, and then populates the input with the correct name.

```
if (defaultOption.length) {
    nm = $.map(locs, function(obj) {
      if (obj.id === defaultOption)
        return obj.name; // or return obj.name, whatever.
    });
  }

  $('.typeahead').val(nm);
```

Comment: why did you hardcode locs? what if we need to use the json api provided?
and could you point me to a documentation where there is more information about this part `$(this).data().ttTypeahead.input.trigger('queryChanged', nm);`.
on the typeahead.js documentation there is not even the `queryChanged` event.

Comment: I am using the api call.  But unless you are returning the string value you want to display, you will have to look it up.  If you look at the code, you will see that I'm mapping the default "2" to the name "Canada" to display "Canada" in the text box.

Comment: this line `$(this).data().ttTypeahead.input.trigger('queryChanged', nm);` is a hack using jQuery to get at the full typeahead object.  It allows you to push a value on to the search results.